# What is the text on the center chip on a GTX 690?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I don't have one around me to look, and I need to know what is printed on the black chip in the center of the PCB. I can't post an image, but there is a green square between the two GPUs, and on it a black chip has some text on it.

What is printed on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PLX
>   TECHNOLOGY
>   PEX8747
>   BA80BFBC G
>   1148 TAIWAN
>   NAA983.J7B

Cropped from [this photo](http://images.anandtech.com/doci/5795/GeForce_GTX_690_F_bare_PCB.jpg) found via [Google Images](http://images.google.com/search?q=%22gtx%20690%22&tbs=isz:l).

[image: GTX 690 center chip]

Comment: and what that is, is a PCIe bridge chip to handle having two cores.